# Can I specify my Rails version using .asdf version manager?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asdf-vm

Currently I have [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/#/) for managing my versions of Ruby (`2.6.5`), nodejs, and yarn. I am trying to follow a Rails tutorial with version `5.2.1`.

Running `gem install rails -v 5.2.1` and 
`rails new appname version=5.2.1`.

It still says version `6.0.2.1` application. I am new to Ruby on Rails so there could be something obvious I'm missing or I'm making a bigger deal out of this than it needs to be. But I'd like to follow this rather long tutorial as close as possible. I believe it is installing the correct version of rails under this path.

`~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rails-5.2.1/`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. [Medium blog ...](https://medium.com/luanotes/build-instagram-by-ruby-on-rails-part-1-fef7837ee399)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
rails _5.2.1_ new appname
```